# Oracle database 11g - RMAN delete archive logs

Tags: oracle, rman

I have a problem to delete the archive log files before 5 days. it shows me that error message.

```
RMAN> delete noprompt archivelog all completed before 'sysdate - 5';
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=203 device type=DISK
specification does not match any archived log in the repository
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe there aren't any!

run this and see if there are any archivelogs older than 5 days

```
list backup of archivelog all;
```

Comment: yes there is no backup of archive log, but sir my database directory is increasing gradually?

do you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: i would guess data was being added to your database and therefore it is getting larger

Comment: do you have any idea about discrepancy of block ID's?

Comment: i'd suggest you post another question with as much detail as you can on the block problem